# converting java variable to spring beans

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I am working on spring boot application. I want to define a variable in a class file as bean so that it is being initialised only once. Below is the source code.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

//Load template from source folder
Template template = cfg.getTemplate("src/helloworld.ftl");

// Build the data-model
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("message", "Hello World!");

// Console output
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
template.process(data, out);
out.flush();
```

I want to initialise the configuration object cfg & the template (starting 2 lines of the code) only once during application start and later use them wherever required in application classes.
How can I achieve this with bean?
Or is there any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: read about @Configuration annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is put the instantiation and initialization of the variables in their own method and annotate every method with the `@Bean` annotation.

If you do this, you should annotate the class with `@Configuration`.

The 2 methods of yours would look something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationBean {
    @Bean
    public Configuration configuration() {
        return new Configuration();
    }

    @Bean
    public Template template() {
        return configuration().getTemplate("...");
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you don't want to instantiate the `Configuration` as a separate bean, you can merge the 2 methods above.

======= UPDATE to answer question in the comment =======

If you want to use the newly defined `Template` bean for example in other classes, you need to annotate those classes with `@Component`, so that they become beans as well.

An example:

```
@Component
public class OtherClassBean {
    private final Template template;

    public OtherClassBean(Template template) {
        this.template = template;
    }
}
```

please be careful here, because from now on, you can't manually instantiate `OtherClassBean`, meaning that a line like `new OtherClassBean(...)` is wrong  in 99% of the cases and might result in unexpected behavior.

This is because all beans are meant to be managed by Spring, which can only be achieved if Spring instantiates those classes.

The only exception from this rule of thumb is in my initial answer, where you instantiate a bean in a method that is annotated with `@Bean`.

I know this is a confusing topic for most people trying to learn this, so don't be shy to ask more questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I use this created beans in another Java class? I want to access the template bean. I am new to java and beans. Please help.

Comment: I'll update my answer in a minute to answer this question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just couple of more doubts. Can I use @Autowired to access the Template bean in other class?

Comment: of course. There are multiple ways to inject the `Template` in other classes. The way I showed it is one of them, the `@Autowired` way is another. Read more about these ways here: https://medium.com/@ilyailin7777/all-dependency-injection-types-spring-336da7baf51b

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class and use the @Configuration annotation to load the beans when the application start up.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public Configuration getConfigurationBean(){
        return new Configuration();
    }
}
```